# Issues with trimming string

Tags: visual-c++

Following is a piece of code I used for trimming :

```
SubString.TrimLeft(LogParse[logCount].TrimLeftString);
```

where SubString is CString and LogParse[logCount].TrimLeftString is LPCTSTR.

Following is the output when given three different inputs

1) SubString = "Node No: c7 string"
   LogParse[logCount].TrimLeftString = "Node No: "

Trim Result  - "c7 string" --> Expected

2) SubString = "Node No: dd string"
   LogParse[logCount].TrimLeftString = "Node No: "

Trim Result  - "string" --> Expected is "dd string"

3)  SubString = "Node No: e5 string"
   LogParse[logCount].TrimLeftString = "Node No: "

Trim Result  - "5 string" --> Expected is "e5 string"

Pls let me know if i had did something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you pass as a parameter to TrimLeft is a not a substring, to be removed in its entirety or not at all - it's a list of characters, and each character is trimmed separately.

Think of it as an "array of characters" rather than a "string".  (I know they're almost the same thing in C/C++, but you've got to look past that.)

If you want to remove a specific substring if it appears at the beginning of the string, then I think you'll have to do it as a `Find()` followed by a `Mid()`